# Converting categorical values to binary using pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, type-conversion, categorical-data

I am trying to convert categorical values into binary values using pandas. The idea is to consider every unique categorical value as a feature (i.e. a column) and put 1 or 0 depending on whether a particular object (i.e. row) was assigned to this category. The following is the code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('somedata.csv')
converted_val = data.T.to_dict().values()
vectorizer = DV( sparse = False )
vec_x = vectorizer.fit_transform( converted_val )
numpy.savetxt('out.csv',vec_x,fmt='%10.0f',delimiter=',')
```

My question is, how to **save this converted data with the column names**?. In the above code, I am able to save the data using `numpy.savetxt` function, but this simply saves the array and the column names are lost. Alternatively, is there a much efficient way to perform the above operation?.

Comment: Maybe pd.data.to_csv() would work better. It has a columns argument that takes a sequence and is None by default.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that you are using scikit-learn's `DictVectorizer` to convert the categorical values to binary. In that case, to store the result along with the new column names, you can construct a new DataFrame with values from `vec_x` and columns from `DV.get_feature_names()`. Then, store the DataFrame to disk (e.g. with `to_csv()`) instead of the numpy array.

Alternatively, it is also possible to use `pandas` to do the encoding directly with the [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) function:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'T': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']})
res = pd.get_dummies(data)
res.to_csv('output.csv')
print res
```

Output:

```
   T_A  T_B  T_C  T_D  T_E
0    1    0    0    0    0
1    0    1    0    0    0
2    0    0    1    0    0
3    0    0    0    1    0
4    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: Often you will have binary variables or have some predetermined set of possible values (like A,B,C,D,E), in which case you may want to drop one of the variables, like A in this examle, because the other 4 categories are enough information to uniquely identify each item: item 0 would be stored as [-,0,0,0,0], telings you that the item must belong to A. How to do this:
`pd.get_dummies(data, drop_first=True)`

Answer (score 29):

You mean "one-hot" encoding?

Say you have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
            ['green', 1, 10.1, 0], 
            ['red', 2, 13.5, 1], 
            ['blue', 3, 15.3, 0]])

df.columns = ['color', 'size', 'prize', 'class label']
df
```

[image]

Now, you have multiple options ...

## A) The Tedious Approach

```
color_mapping = {
           'green': (0,0,1),
           'red': (0,1,0),
           'blue': (1,0,0)}

df['color'] = df['color'].map(color_mapping)
df
```

[image]

```
import numpy as np
y = df['class label'].values
X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
X = np.apply_along_axis(func1d= lambda x: np.array(list(x[0]) + list(x[1:])), axis=1, arr=X)

print('Class labels:', y)
print('\nFeatures:\n', X)
```

Yielding:

```
Class labels: [0 1 0]

Features:
 [[  0.    0.    1.    1.   10.1]
 [  0.    1.    0.    2.   13.5]
 [  1.    0.    0.    3.   15.3]]
```

## B) Scikit-learn's `DictVectorizer`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
dvec = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)

X = dvec.fit_transform(df.transpose().to_dict().values())
X
```

Yielding:

```
array([[  0. ,   0. ,   1. ,   0. ,  10.1,   1. ],
       [  1. ,   0. ,   0. ,   1. ,  13.5,   2. ],
       [  0. ,   1. ,   0. ,   0. ,  15.3,   3. ]])
```

## C) Pandas' `get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. The the dummies is what I was exactly looking for.